# Function undeclared(first use this function)

Tags: c++

i'm working on Matrix class,but i cant figure it out why i get this error since i already defined problematic function(Dopisi()).This is what i have so far:

This is what i have so far:

```
#include<IOStream>
using namespace std;

class Matrica{

private:int Duzina;
    int Sirina;
    int** pok;

public:
    Matrica(){//default constructor
        Duzina=0;
        Sirina=0;
        int i,j;
        pok=new int* [Duzina];
        for(i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
            pok[i]=new int[Sirina];

        }
    }
    Matrica(int duz,int sir){//constructor
        Duzina=duz;
        Sirina=sir;
        int i,j;
        pok=new int* [Duzina];
        for(i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
            pok[i]=new int[Sirina];
            for(j=0;j<Sirina;j++){
                pok[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    void Dodaj(int i,int j){//add one element
        cout<<"Unesite element ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
        cin>>pok[i][j];
    }
    void Popuni(){//fill entire matrix
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<Duzina;i++)
            for(j=0;j<Sirina;j++)
                Dodaj(i,j);
    }
    Matrica(Matrica& mat){//copy constructor
        Duzina=mat.Duzina;
        Sirina=mat.Sirina;
        int i,j;
        pok=new int* [Duzina];
        for(i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
            pok[i]=new int[Sirina];
            for(j=0;j<Sirina;j++){
                pok[i][j]=mat.pok[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    ~Matrica(){}
    int max(int a,int b){//max value
        if(a>b)return a;
        else
            return b;
    }
    void Ispis(){//cout
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Sirina;j++){
                cout<<pok[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    Matrica& operator =(const Matrica& x){
        for(int i=0;i<Duzina;i++)
            delete pok[i];

        Duzina=x.Duzina;
        Sirina=x.Sirina;
        for(int i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Sirina;j++){
                pok[i][j]=x.pok[i][j];
            }
        }
        return *this; 
    }
    Matrica Dopisi(const Matrica a,const Matrica b);
};
Matrica Matrica::Dopisi(const Matrica a,const Matrica b){//function must take two      matrices 
    int i,j,duz,sir;
    duz=max(a.Duzina,b.Duzina);
    sir=a.Sirina+b.Sirina;
    Matrica temp(duz,sir);
    for(i=0;i<a.Duzina;i++){
        for(j=0;j<a.Sirina;j++){
            temp.pok[i][j]=a.pok[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<b.Duzina;i++){
        for(j=0;j<b.Sirina;j++){
            temp.pok[i][j+a.Sirina]=b.pok[i][j];
        }
    }
    temp.Ispis();
    // return temp;
}
int main(){
    Matrica mat1(3,3);
    mat1.Popuni();
    mat1.Ispis();
    Matrica mat2(4,4);
    mat2.Popuni();
    mat2.Ispis();
    mat2=mat1;
    mat2.Ispis();
    Matrica mat3;
    mat3=Dopisi(mat1,mat2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.Names of variables and methods are in Serbian,hope you'll figure it out.Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error and at which line?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code.

Answer (score 2):

`Dopisi` is a *member* function in the `Matrica` class. If you want it to be a free-standing function it should be declared or defined *outside* the class.

If you want it to be able to access private member, then declare it as a `friend` function, or make it a `static` member function (but then you have to call it as `Matrica::Dopisi(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Make the function

```
public:
static Matrica Dopisi(const Matrica &a,const Matrica &b);
```

Then you can call it outside the class as

```
mat3 = Matrica::Dopisi(mat1,mat2);
```

without needing an instance of the class

Comment: Yes. I'd also recommend passing a and b by const *reference*: `const Matrica &a`

Comment: Good point. That would be the standard thing I would do, I didn't read what I was copy pasting closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Dopisi` as if it were a regular function. It is a member function and so needs to be called on an instance of class `Matrica`. The actual style of this function would indicate that it would be better as a non-member function as calling this function as currently, it requires an instance of `Matrica` to call on but also takes 2 instances of `Matrica` as arguments and also returns a fourth. Thus you have 4 instances in total. It seems more appropriate to use a nonmember function taking t instances of `Matrica` and returning the result.

This would of course also require getter/setter functions for the private members of the class that are accessed within that function.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `Dopisi` function as a class method (put it inside your class declaration), but then you call it as a global function. For example, it could be called as `mat3.Dopisi(mat1, mat2)`.

In your case, `Dopisi` needs to have access to `Matrica` class, so just make it a friend-function:

...

```
// in class declaration:
friend Matrica Dopisi(const Matrica a,const Matrica b);
```

...

```
// in function definition:
Matrica Dopisi(const Matrica a,const Matrica b){//function must take two      matrices
```

...

// leave your function call as it is

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem with the function the class definition is invalid. First of all the destructor does not release memory pointed by pok. Also the assignment operator is incorrect.

```
Matrica& operator =(const Matrica& x){
    for(int i=0;i<Duzina;i++)
        delete pok[i];

    Duzina=x.Duzina;
    Sirina=x.Sirina;
    for(int i=0;i<Duzina;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Sirina;j++){
            pok[i][j]=x.pok[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this; 
}
```

First of all instead of `delete pok[i];` shall be `delete []pok[i];` Also you did not release used memory and allocate a new memory according to new values of Duzina and Sirina.

So the operator function has undefined behavior and without doubts its work will result in program exception.